# Get github OAuth token without secret

Tags: javascript, github, oauth, oauth-2.0, github-api

I'm trying to create a github app using just static pages with no server side logic. Is there a way to get an access token  without having to make the access token post with a secret key?

This code is going to be on a public repo served with `gh-pages`, so I can't store the secret key. I know dropbox and other oauth providers allow this, is there any way to do with github?

Reference: https://developer.github.com/guides/basics-of-authentication/#providing-a-callback

Answer (score 2):

No -- it's not possible to complete the GitHub OAuth flow from client-side JavaScript. You need to use a server component.